# How to separate items in enumerate with colored lines?

Tags: lists, enumerate, addlines

I have a list of definitions. I want them to be separated by a line, something like below: [image: Definitions list]
Also, I want to customize the color of lines and numbers.

I tried to use enumerate and got stuck at creating lines between items and changing the color.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could just load `xcolor` and do `\color{blue}{\rule[1.75pt]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}` or something along this lines.

Comment: @marmot But where do I put the line inside enumerate. If I write this after each item then it draws the line as a continuation to the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are looking for something like this:

[image]

This was made using a customised `enumitem` environment that hijacks the `\item` command and replaces it with `\colouredItem`. The `\colouredItem` command takes two arguments:

- An optional argument giving the colour used for the line and the number. In the code below `#1` can be one of `g`, for gray, `r` for red, `b` for blue, or `g` for green. Under the hood, this syntax uses `\str_case:nn` from `LaTeX3`.
- A mandatory second argument gives the term being defined. This is typeset using `\textbf{...}`.

With this in place the image above was created using:

```
  \begin{colouredenum}
    \item{Definition 1} description
    \item{Definition 2} description
    \item[r]{Definition 3} description
    \item[b]{Definition 4} description
  \end{colouredenum}
```

This code will only work if each definition line fits on one physical line. If the definition goes over many lines then it will be a mess. It is possible to modify the code to cope with this case but it would be a little more complicated.

Here is the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlist{colouredenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[colouredenum]{
  before=\let\item\colouredItem,
  labelindent=0pt,
  labelsep=0pt,
  labelwidth=0pt,
  leftmargin=0pt,
}
\let\realItem\item

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_linecolour_tl
\newcommand\colouredline[1]{
    \str_case:nn {#1} {
      {g} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {gray} }
      {r} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {red} }
      {b} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {blue} }
      {g} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {green} }
    }
    \realItem[] % we want to underline the number so we fake it
    \hspace*{0.1mm} % need something here to start the line
    \rlap{\textcolor{\tl_use:N\l_linecolour_tl}{\rule[-3pt]{\linewidth}{1pt}}}%
    \refstepcounter{enumi} % insert item number now that the line is drawn
    \textcolor{\tl_use:N\l_linecolour_tl}{\theenumi.}\space
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand\colouredItem { O{g} m }{
  \colouredline{#1}
  \textbf{#2}\space
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{colouredenum}
    \item{Definition 1} description
    \item{Definition 2} description
    \item[r]{Definition 3} description
    \item[b]{Definition 4} description
  \end{colouredenum}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

As I mentioned, a variant on this idea caters for multi-line definitions. The idea is to draw the coloured line for the previous definition at the start of the next `\item`. In the code below this is done using the macro  `\lastColouredLine`. The revised macros produce the following output using exactly the same syntax:

[image]

You can adjust the spacing of the lines by changing the `\rule[0.8em]` and `\vspace*{-1.5em}` in the definition of the `\l_lastcolouredline` macro.

Here is the new code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlist{colouredenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[colouredenum]{
  before=\let\item\colouredItem\let\lastColouredLine\relax,
  after=\lastColouredLine,
  labelindent=0pt,
  labelsep=0pt,
  labelwidth=0pt,
  leftmargin=0pt,
}
\let\realItem\item

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_linecolour_tl
\newcommand\l_lastcolouredline{
  \leavevmode\newline
  \textcolor{\tl_use:N\l_linecolour_tl}{\rule[0.8em]{\linewidth}{1pt}}
  \vspace*{-1.5em}
}
\newcommand\colouredline[1]{
    \lastColouredLine % insert the last coloured line
    \str_case:nn {#1} {
      {g} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {gray} }
      {r} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {red} }
      {b} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {blue} }
      {g} {\tl_set:Nn \l_linecolour_tl {green} }
    }
    \realItem[] % we want to underline the number so we fake it
    \let\lastColouredLine\l_lastcolouredline
    \refstepcounter{enumi} % insert item number now that the line is drawn
    \textcolor{\tl_use:N\l_linecolour_tl}{\theenumi.}\space
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\NewDocumentCommand\colouredItem { O{g} m }{%
  \colouredline{#1}%
  \textbf{#2}\space
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{colouredenum}
    \item{Definition 1} here is a longer description that goes on and on
      and on and on and on and on and on and on
    \item{Definition 2} description
    \item[r]{Definition 3} description here is a longer description that
      goes on and on and on and on and on and on and on and on
    \item[b]{Definition 4} description
  \end{colouredenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like how clean the final usage is. But, as you said, if the definition goes over multiple lines, it becomes a mess. What if we approach this in a different way using tables. Then we'll have to hide all the vertical lines and display row numbers. Though I'm not sure if that'd be easier or better.