# Enumitem: next line to be colored using macro or command

Tags: color, enumitem

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1.1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    
    {\color{blue!60} Next line for explanation}
    \item item 1
    
    {\color{blue!60} Next line for explanation}
    \item item 1
    
    {\color{blue!60} Next line for explanation}
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Subsection1.1.1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    
    Next line for explanation 1
    \item item 2
    
    Next line for explanation 2
    \item item 3
    
    Next line for explanation 3
\end{enumerate}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    
    Next line for explanation 1
    \item item 2
    
    Next line for explanation 2
    \item item 3
    
    Next line for explanation 3
\end{enumerate}
\section{Section2.2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    
    Next line for explanation 1
    \item item 2
    
    Next line for explanation 2
    \item item 3
    
    Next line for explanation 3
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Subsection2.2.1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    
    Next line for explanation 1
    \item item 2
    
    Next line for explanation 2
    \item item 3
    
    Next line for explanation 3
\end{enumerate}
\chapter{Chapter3}
\section{Section3.1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    
    Next line for explanation 1
    \item item 2
    
    Next line for explanation 2
    \item item 3
    
    Next line for explanation 3
\end{enumerate}
\subsection{Subsection3.1.1}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item item 1
    
    Next line for explanation 1
    \item item 2
    
    Next line for explanation 2
    \item item 3
    
    Next line for explanation 3
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I made the next line (of item of the `enumitem`) colored blue to show some explanation as you can see in the figure.

[image]

It is OK for a list. But I have a lot of lists in my document as you see in the code. How can I automate this thing using macro or command to make (*colored blue*) the next line of each `enumitem` that can easily managed.

To say clearly, I want all the lines `Next line for explanation 1/2/3` to be blue colored.

Comment: A related query: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432945/how-to-separate-items-in-enumerate-with-colored-lines

Answer (score 1):

One simple, yet imperfect solution would be to create a `newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\bitem}[2]{
    \item #1
    
    {\color{blue!60} #2}
    }
```

And to use it whenever needed:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \bitem{item 1}{The blue nest line for explanation 1}
    \item item 2
    
    Nest line for explanation 2
    \item item 3
    
    Nest line for explanation 3
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: enumitem formatting]

Although I'm pretty sure that some Expl3 expert would come with handier solution.

Comment: It's not much easier to manage. I must edit all the `\item` in this way which is really tough.

Comment: I know that. I'm just not clever enough to figure another good solution out. Hope someone will. But since your item title and the rest of its content are considered all the same, it could be difficult to distinguished what is going to be coloured.

Comment: To say clearly, I want all the lines `Next line for explanation 1/2/3` to be blue colored.

Comment: It was perfectly clear to me. Colouring everything (including "item 1") in blue is easy, but discriminating what is to be couloured in the enumerate content is another challenge.